# Why we shouldnt use 'www' with wordpress multisite

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

i have a wordpress multi site and wordpress advice me: do not use 'www' in your domain primary url.

but i want to my url is:

```html
https:// www. domain. com.
```

so i installed my domain with www.

i install second site (english version) with multisite is this give me a problem in future?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress Multisite allows you to create a network of similar or related WordPress websites and blogs with just one WordPress Installation; however, Multisite is not for everyone.

It is ideal for companies that need to spin up hundreds of micro or niche sites quickly.

Disadvantages of multisite:

The things that make Multisite a great sharer also contribute to its flaws.

1. Migrations are exceedingly complex as each site shares one database.
   Migrating one site off your network is very difficult.
2. You cannot truly separate users; each one will still have access to
   the entire network. You cannot create separate system users for SFTP
   uploads.
3. A plugin cannot be installed on only a single site in the network.
   Once the network administrator installs the plugin, it will be
   available for all sites on the network. If you delete a plugin, any
   site using that plugin will be affected. Some plugins do not work
   with Multisite.

Multisite can be extremely complex, it would be best to use a standard WordPress installation or multiple installations on a single server if your goal is any of the following:

1. To manage a small number of different sites.
2. To organize your content by categories.
3. To do development work before pushing the site into production.